# With which instrument will I find it easier to join a band? Keyboard or guitar?

Tags: guitar, keyboard, band

I like indie music, pop rock, and j-rock. Would I find it easier to join a band of these genres playing the keyboard or guitar?

Comment: This is likely to be judged an opinion based question and closed. You should read the guidance in the Help Center https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: Why not doing what you prefer most? You will probably get good faster ending in more time to find a band that needs the instrument you chose?

Answer (score 2):

The guitar is used in all the genres you mentioned. I would be inclined to say guitar, but at the same time, keyboard players are harder to come by in my experience. I would say focus on guitar, but keep the keyboard as an option. Being a multi-instrumentalist is pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not an option you mention, but there are *so* many guitarists out there, and lots of keys players, but in most genres, there are not nearly as many bassists available.

The bassist governs where rhythm and harmony overlap. It's a very powerful role.

Answer (score 0):

As I am somewhat proficient in both instruments, I would advise to play guitar if you're more self-confident, as the guitar is the main melody, but piano if you're interested in playing the general chords.

Comment: I don't understand the logic behind this answer. I play both, and neither is necessarily main melody **or** chords.